# How to force browsers to show a modal before sorting a table via javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I'm using the stupid-table plugin, found on github. (this: https://github.com/joequery/Stupid-Table-Plugin)

I'm handling a very large table. Firefox and Chrome change the table sorting in less than 3 seconds. IE10,11 and Edge take more than 30 seconds. And also some mobile browsers, first of all Safari on old iPad 1

I'd like to show a modal '`sorting, please wait`', before the sorting take place and then hide the modal after sorting ends.

I tried this:

```
            var super_table = $('#result_div #result_table').stupidtable();    


            super_table.bind('beforetablesort', function (event, data) {
                // data.column - the index of the column sorted after a click
                // data.direction - the sorting direction (either asc or desc)
                // $(this) - this table object

                $('#sorting_modal').modal('show');

                console.log('The sorting direction: ' + data.direction);
                console.log('The column index: ' + data.column);
            });

            super_table.bind('aftertablesort', function (event, data) {
                // data.column - the index of the column sorted after a click
                // data.direction - the sorting direction (either asc or desc)
                // $(this) - this table object

                $('#sorting_modal').modal('hide');

                console.log('The sorting direction: ' + data.direction);
                console.log('The column index: ' + data.column);
            });
```

Two problems:

1. On Firefox and Chrome, all is so fast that user now see only a 'flash' in the screen, and so is only annoying to users
2. On IE the sort start immediately after the request to show the modal, but the sorting is "blocking" IE, so user see 30 seconds of "nothing happening" on the screen and then a flash (modal showed, table sorted, modal hidden)

Ideally:

1. User clicks, activating the stupid-table plugin
2. on 'before table sorting' event I want to show a modal
3. wait 1/2 second
4. do the real sorting
5. on 'after table sorting' event I want to first update the table
6. And then hide the modal, about 1/2 second after the sorting end.

I don't know if there is a way to force browsers (and the plugin itself) to 'wait' after the modal is showed before really doing the sorting

Comment: At first instance, I thought you are absuing that `table plugin` you found on GitHub.. :D

Comment: I added the link, sorry

Comment: you can try `setTimeout` here, but I am afraid you might need to modify the plugin part itself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setTimeout to simulate a little delay before hiding the modal:

```
super_table.bind('aftertablesort', function (event, data) {
       // data.column - the index of the column sorted after a click
       // data.direction - the sorting direction (either asc or desc)
       // $(this) - this table object

       setTimeout(function() {
              $('#sorting_modal').modal('hide');
       }, 1000);

       console.log('The sorting direction: ' + data.direction);
       console.log('The column index: ' + data.column);
});
```

Comment: I'ts only a parte of the solution, but it's better than nothing